# 境界条件を含んだランダムウォークver2

Tags: python, python3, julia

以前、境界条件を含んだランダムウォークについて質問させていただきました。python３でかいてあったので、今回はこれをJuliaで書き直しましたが、エラーなしで動くのですが、結果がおかしく、pythonと全く同じように書いてあるはずなのですが、間違えがわかりません。

```
function main()
    n = 3
    count0=0
    count1=0
    count2=0
    count3=0
    count4=0
    count5=0
    count6=0
    count7=0
    stage = zeros(Int8,n,n,n)
    stage[:,:,1]=[1 1 1;1 0 1;1 1 1]
    stage[:,:,2]=[1 0 1;0 0 0;1 0 1]
    stage[:,:,3]=[1 1 1;1 0 1;1 1 1]
    #println(walk)
    for itr in 1:10
        walk = zeros(Int8,n,n,n)
        walk[1,1,1]=1
        for t in 0:10
            if t==0
                continue
            else
                next_walk = zeros(Int8,n,n,n)
                number=rand(UnitRange{Int8}(1:6))
                for x = 1:n, y = 1:n, z =1:n
                    x1 = ((x-1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                    x2 = ((x+1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                    y1 = ((y-1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                    y2 = ((y+1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                    z1 = ((z-1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1 
                    z2 = ((z+1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                    if stage[x,y,z]== 0
                        continue
                    else
                        if walk[x,y,z]== 0
                            continue
                        else
                            if number == 1
                                if stage[x2,y,z]==1
                                    next_walk[x2,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                else
                                    next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                end
                            elseif number == 2
                                if stage[x,y2,z]==1
                                    next_walk[x,y2,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                else
                                    next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                end
                            elseif number == 3
                                if stage[x,y,z2]==1
                                    next_walk[x,y,z2]=walk[x,y,z]
                                else
                                    next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                end
                            elseif number == 4
                                if stage[x1,y,z]==1
                                    next_walk[x1,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                else
                                    next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                end
                            elseif number == 5
                                if stage[x,y1,z]==1
                                    next_walk[x,y1,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                else
                                    next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                end
                            elseif number == 6
                                if stage[x,y,z1]==1
                                    next_walk[x,y,z1]=walk[x,y,z]
                                else
                                    next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                walk = next_walk
                end
            if t == 0
                if walk[1,1,1]==1
                    count0 += 1
                else
                    continue
                end
            elseif t == 6
                if walk[1,1,1]==1
                    count1 += 1
                else
                    continue
                end
            elseif t == 36
                if walk[1,1,1]==1
                    count2 += 1
                else
                    continue
                end
            elseif t == 216
                if walk[1,1,1]==1
                    count3 += 1
                else
                    continue
                end
            else
                continue
                    #1296,7776,46656
            end
            end
        end
    #println("t=0:",count0,"\n","t=6:",count1,"\n","t=36:",count2,"\n","t=216:",count3,"\n","t=1296:",count4,"\n","t=7776:",count5,"\n","t=46656:",count6,"\n")
    end
    println("t=0:",count0,"\n","t=6:",count1,"\n","t=36:",count2,"\n","t=216:",count3,"\n","t=1296:",count4,"\n","t=7776:",count5,"\n","t=46656:",count6,"\n")
end
main()
```

ランダムウォークの再帰性ができているか、t=0で今回はcount0=10になるはずなのですが、０になったままで、すこしおかしいのですが、どこが間違っているのでしょうか、、、。
結果（乱数なので一例）
    t=0:0
    t=6:3
    t=36:0
    t=216:0
    t=1296:0
    t=7776:0
    t=46656:0
宜しくお願い致します。わかり次第自分も報告します。

Comment: `for t in 0:10` の直後に `if t==0 continue` という処理がありますので、count0 は 0 のままですね。。。

Comment: あ、t==0のときは何もしないという意味になってしまうということですか、、

Comment: それだとpythonでいう何もしないpassがjuliaにはないので、、、厳しいですね

Comment: いま、動きを確認したら、そもそもランダムウォークがちゃんと動いてませんでした

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のjuliaのコードでうまく動いたと思います。間違えなどございましたら、ご指摘のほどお願いします。

```
function main()
    n = 3
    count0=0
    count1=0
    count2=0
    count3=0
    count4=0
    count5=0
    count6=0
    count7=0
    stage = zeros(Int8,n,n,n)
    stage[:,:,1]=[1 1 1;1 0 1;1 1 1]
    stage[:,:,2]=[1 0 1;0 0 0;1 0 1]
    stage[:,:,3]=[1 1 1;1 0 1;1 1 1]
    #println(walk)
    for itr in 1:10
        walk = zeros(Int8,n,n,n)
        walk[1,1,1]=1
        for t in 0:6
            next_walk = zeros(Int8,n,n,n)
            number=rand(UnitRange{Int8}(1:6))
            if t==0
                count0 += 1
            else
                for x = 1:n, y = 1:n, z =1:n
                    x1 = ((x-1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                    x2 = ((x+1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                    y1 = ((y-1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                    y2 = ((y+1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                    z1 = ((z-1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1 
                    z2 = ((z+1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                    if stage[x,y,z]== 0
                        continue
                    else
                        if walk[x,y,z]== 0
                            continue
                        else
                            if number == 1
                                if stage[x2,y,z]==1
                                    next_walk[x2,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                else
                                    next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                end
                            elseif number == 2
                                if stage[x,y2,z]==1
                                    next_walk[x,y2,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                else
                                    next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                end
                            elseif number == 3
                                if stage[x,y,z2]==1
                                    next_walk[x,y,z2]=walk[x,y,z]
                                else
                                    next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                end
                            elseif number == 4
                                if stage[x1,y,z]==1
                                    next_walk[x1,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                else
                                    next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                end
                            elseif number == 5
                                if stage[x,y1,z]==1
                                    next_walk[x,y1,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                else
                                    next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                end
                            elseif number == 6
                                if stage[x,y,z1]==1
                                    next_walk[x,y,z1]=walk[x,y,z]
                                else
                                    next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            　　walk = copy(next_walk)
            #println(t,walk,"\n")
            if t == 6
                if walk[1,1,1]==1
                    count1 += 1
                else
                    continue
                end
            elseif t == 36
                if walk[1,1,1]==1
                    count2 += 1
                else
                    continue
                end
            elseif t == 216
                if walk[1,1,1]==1
                    count3 += 1
                else
                    continue
                end
            else
                continue
                    #1296,7776,46656
            end
            end
        end
    #println("t=0:",count0,"\n","t=6:",count1,"\n","t=36:",count2,"\n","t=216:",count3,"\n","t=1296:",count4,"\n","t=7776:",count5,"\n","t=46656:",count6,"\n")
    end
    println("t=0:",count0,"\n","t=6:",count1,"\n","t=36:",count2,"\n","t=216:",count3,"\n","t=1296:",count4,"\n","t=7776:",count5,"\n","t=46656:",count6,"\n")
end
main()

t=0:10
t=6:3
t=36:0
t=216:0
t=1296:0
t=7776:0
t=46656:0
```